# Should conditions go inside or outside of function/method

Tags: php

What is preferable: A function that decides itself if it should do anything, or deciding whether to call that function?

```
function x() {
    if ($userIsLoggedIn) {
        alwaysHelloUser();
    }

    if ($visitorRegion != 'US') {
        alwaysDisplayNoInternationalShipping();
    }

    if ($day == 'Sunday') {
        alwaysLockDownStore();
    }
}

function alwaysLockDownStore() {
    //close store
    //offer alternative store
    //show opening hours
    //display form for user leaving order for next day
    exit("Sorry, we are closed!");
}
```

or

```
function y() {
    perhapsSayHelloUser($user);
    maybeDisplayNoInternationalShipping($region);
    sometimesLockDownStore($day);
}

function sometimesLockDownStore($day) {
    if ($day == 'Sunday') {
        //close store
        //offer alternative store
        //show opening hours
        //display form for user leaving order for next day
        exit ("Sorry, we are closed!");
    }
}
```

The example is trivial, but imagine enabling functions using configuration or access rights. Is there an accepted standard? My gut tells me to go for `y()` when there is something like `exit()` involved, breaking the normal flow. Otherwise, encapsulation and DRY would favor `x()`. What do you think?

**Edit** I've expended the example. My question is really: If there is a condition on which a function/method should be executed, should that control take place in the function (tidy but outcome is uncertain) or outside it (calling is verbose, but expected output is always the same)?

Comment: **Primarily Opinion Based** - "Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."

Comment: I will say the first one, just because if the condition is false you will not calling the second function, so you will save few time and some performances

Comment: Second has not point, you have a wrapper x() over someTimes...(). It's the same if you directly call someTimes...().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd prefer to keep the main functionality in the function. Extra logic outside. Because the function will do just that what is intented. Or you would everytime run the function needed or not. Depending how complex your problem will be.

```
function lockStoreOnDay($day) {
    // do locking
    return "Sorry, we are closed on $day!";
}

echo lockStoreOnDay('Sunday'); //will print "Sorry, we are closed on Sunday!"
echo lockStoreOnDay('Saturday'); //will print "Sorry, we are closed on Saturday!"
```

Generally: Why not use a Class?

If you have access rights or a configuration this information could be stored in an Array or Object. So you iterate through the Array or search for your keyword and than process whatever should be processed. I. e. make a function call.

```
function lockStoreOnDay()
{
    //do locking
    return "Sorry, we are closed!";
}

$config_closeOnDay = array (
    'Sunday'
);

foreach ($config_closeOnDay as $dayToCloseOn) {
    echo lockStoreOnDay();
}
```

Maybe this helps.

Comment: in your first example, the function should not do anything on certain conditions (it should only display something on Sunday). Would you put that condition inside or outside the function? Classes are nice, but the problem would remain the same.

Comment: Conditions outside because if the condition is met the function has to do it's job. Depeding on the function and the job :)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have such constraints hardcoded inside function. You should aim for something like:

```
function isStoreLocked($dayToCheck, $daysLocked)
    {
    // You can replace "locking" logic with database or something
    // There shouldn't be an raw array of days inside code
    return in_array($dayToCheck, $daysLocked);
    }
```

Then in your code:

```
$curentDayName = date('l');
$lockedDays = array('Saturday', 'Sunday');
if(isStoreLocked($currentDayName, $daysLocked))
    {
    die('Sorry, store is locked!');
    }
```

To give context to my answer: if you do it using a framework (my choice is Symfony2) `isStoreLocked` should be a service or a repository method and it should be called inside controller while returning Response (rather than simple `die()`).